# Can't access value of checkbox on button click c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am binding data to a gridview in Page_Load and then in the same Page_Load I am adding a column of check boxes which are not part of the databinding.

Then when a button is pressed I want to check to see if any of the boxes are checked.  However, when I look for the checkboxes in my button_click method the checkboxes seem to have disappeared entirely.

I am looking for them with

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
{
   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("check" + gvr.Cells[2].Text);
   ...
}
```

I have a hunch they might be getting destroyed on postback but I'm not sure how to make sure this doesnt happen.

Everything in my Page_Load method is contained in a if(!IsPostBack) statement.

some asked for my page_load:

`foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
                {`

```
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();

                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

                cb.ID = "check" + gvr.Cells[2].Text;

                tc.Controls.AddAt(0, cb);

                gvr.Cells.AddAt(0, tc);

            }
```

I think is the relevant part.

Comment: Show us your `Page_Load` event please.

Comment: What is in Cells[2]? The text cannot be altered?

Comment: Have you disabled view state for the page? If yes, mark _EnableViewState="true"_ at least for the checkbox and other controls, of which you want to persist values during postbacks. If no, then post your Page_Load event, and aspx part as well, if you are doing any processing in javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating dynamic controls, put the code that creates them (i.e. the CheckBoxes) in the `Page_Init` and not in the `Page_Load`.
You should also double-check that the **order** in which the checkboxes are created and the **ids** that they receive are the same in each postback.
If for some reason `gvr.Cells[2].Text` changes between postbacks, you should probably think of a better logic in which you id your checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the answer but one issue.  I need to access a gridview which is created in page_load in order to create my new dynamic controls (I need to know how many controls to make).